# Is there a 3D analogue of angle?

Tags: units, geometry

A one-dimensional angle is a wedge, almost like a slice of pizza.  A two-dimensional angle is an angle squared, like the cone of light produced by a flashlight.  This is called a [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle).  **Is there an intuitive meaning of a 3D angle (i.e. angle cubed)?**

Comment: sure: you're generally talking about the n-1 dimensional surface that is the boundary of a volume element (normalized to the modulus).  This extends quite naturally into n dimensions, though I'm not certain its a unique extension of angle into higher dimensions...

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This should be migrated to math.stack exchange, seems a very on topic question if you write it correctly.